# equality of algebraic expressions in Mathematica

Tags: functions, function-construction

Is there an inbuilt function to test equality of symbolic expressions in Mathematica? For example, I want to declare a function g that test whether a certain function f of x and y is identically 0 or not modulo 2. I used `PolynomialMod[f,2]==0` which returns True when f is 0 modulo 2 but does not give False when f is non-zero modulo 2. Since f is not given to us, thus g needs to know that the variables in f are x and y. So, one function that could be helpful is

`g1[f_, {x_, y_}] :=`function that accepts f as a function of variables x and y and then returns it after evaluation at `x->x0` and `y-> y0`

I am sure this is supersimple but just don't know. Please guide.

Answer (score 4):

You have a broad question - a few different ones, in fact. To answer the first one, you can use `TrueQ` which tests whether an expression is equal to True or not:

```
g[f_]:=TrueQ[PolynomialMod[f, 2] == 0]

g[x+y]
(* False *)

g[2x + 4y]
(* True *)
```